# Optimization problem - More Hired - Less Produced Each

Tags: calculus, derivatives

*Brilliantly realizing that there is a demand for chocolate candy in the shape of
an integral sign, you start a business to produce such items. Efficiency experts determine
that if you employ 30 people to make these candies, each person will produce 500 packages of
chocolate integrals in a workday. However, for each additional person hired, this daily yield
decreases by 10 packages per worker. How many people should you hire to maximize the total
number of packages produced?*

So I'm doing my last bit of studying for my final and I came across this problem. I've set this up as (30+x)(500-10x). Don't quite remember where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to maximize $f(x)=(30+x)(500-10x)$. The textbook method -- which ought to spring to your mind immediately when you see an optimization problem -- is of course to differentiate it and solve $f'(x)=0$ to find possible local extrema, and then check if any of those are global maxima.

However, just to show there's more than one way to do things, here's a method that uses no calculus:

Your $f(x)$ is a product of two polynomials of first degree; we know that such a product is always a polynomial of *second* degree; so its graph is a *parabola* with vertical axis. When $x$ is large positive or negative, the value of $f(x)$ is negative, so the legs of the parabola point *down*, and the point we're looking for is the *apex* of the parabola.

The $x$-coordinate of the apex of the parabola is halfway between its two roots. The roots are easy to find, because each of the factors $30+x$ and $500-10x$ contribute one root each. Solving $30+x=0$ gives $x=-30$; solving $500-10x=0$ gives $x=50$.

So the $x$-coordinate of the apex is halfway between $-30$ and $50$, that is, at $x=\frac{-30+50}{2}=\frac{20}{2}=10$.

So $x=10$ at the maximum, and you should hire 10 people in addition to the 30 your experts assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Henning Makholm** already showed the method which does not make use of calculus, I'll show the other one, just for the sake of the completeness.

You want to maximize $f(x) = (30 + x)(500 - 10x) = -10x^2 + 200x + 15000$. When $f'(x_0) = 0$ $x_0$ is a local maximum (or minimum). Since $f(x)$ represents a parabola pointing downwards it will have a local (and global) maximum.

$$f'(x) = 0 \implies -20x + 200 = 0 \implies \boxed{\displaystyle x = 10}$$

Therefore $10$ more experts should be hired.